# How to Deploy Google Apps Script for Domain?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I would like to make available to all the users of our Google Apps domain, but I don't want to publish it to the Chrome store. We would like to avoid deploying it from a single user account. How is this normally done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on your use case, but there are a number of ways this might be achieved from publishing a [code library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) (and limiting the sharing of the link), hosting it in a [Google Site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets) to publishing it as a [url triggered webservice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps).

It depends on whether you want to share the functionality to others or literally the code.

Comment: Both, now that you mention it. Thanks for the input - I really like the idea of deploying a url triggered web app, and linking to it via an extension or an installable app in Chrome. The crx files could be deployed with the browser and distributed that way.