# Google app script to edit another script

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-api

I have an app script that is an MCQ quiz, it askes the user questions and grades them etc. It randomly pulls a set number of questions out of a pool (a spread sheet).

I am trying to build a backend interface for teachers to use to make their own quizzes and I was thinking for each quiz it would make a copy of the template scrip but it would need to edit the properties in the template script. if this is even posible how would i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a standalone script to present the multiple choice items, then you can share the script with others and they can run it under their own quotas. I stumbled on [this presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/15ChisW--HBA4jNgnO3O0T3w4SpqRm3WEGGdwZGFZuhw/edit#slide=id.p18) that does a pretty good job of explaining it... too bad there isn't any audio, I bet a few more words would help. Pay particular attention to the deployment discussion, starting around slide 51.

Rather than editing properties in a script, the script could simply use [User Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties) to store a particular teacher's information, including the ID of the document that contains their questions, say. That way, you don't need to customize the script for different users.

This previous question might also help: [How to Deploy Google Apps Script for Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079581/how-to-deploy-google-apps-script-for-domain).

Since stand-alone scripts are `[type:application/vnd.google-apps.script][3]`, it's conceivable that one script could edit another. I hope someone else puts together an answer doing that.